# AutoCompleteTextView dropdown not showing

Tags: android, material-design

I have a basic activity with an `AutoCompleteTextView`. I am trying to use it as a Exposed Dropdown Menu [1] to pick from a list of options, as per the Material Design documentation. [2]

However, when I click the `TextInputLayout`, the dropdown does not appear - although the arrow does flip.

What have I missed?

[image]

`MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) // edit, the mistake is here - see my answer.

        val items = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, items)
        binding.positionPickerField.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="enter your starting position"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/position_picker_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />
```

[1] https://material.io/components/menus#exposed-dropdown-menu
[2] https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus

Comment: Try to type anything man.

Comment: @SamChen I'm trying to make a spinner, so typing is disabled - see `android:inputType="none" `. I did also try changing this to `android:inputType="autoComplete"`, and then typed, but this did not help.

Comment: Try `android:completionThreshold="0"`

Comment: And why don't you just use `Spinner`?

Comment: @SamChen setting the threshold to 0 did not help. 
I went for this implementation as it is recommended in the MD guidelines. I might try spinner instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not setting up the viewbinding correctly.
The fix was in `onCreate()`:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val view = binding.root
setContentView(view)
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities

Answer (score 0):

You have not added threshold value in the `AutoCompleteTextView`.
Just add the method -

```
binding.positionPickerField.setThreshold(1); // will start working from first character
```

Comment: This should not be needed, it should work without it.

Comment: This didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: Are you typing any character in the textview?

Comment: No, I am trying to make a spinner with typing disabled

Comment: Try after changing threshold value to 0, setThreshold(0)

Comment: @tronku setting the threshold value to 0 did not help